# Powershell 4.0 throwing error as invalid command Invoke-MsBuild

Tags: powershell-4.0

As I try to use the Invoke-Command module, Powershell is throwing and error.

```
      Error: "The term 'Invoke-MsBuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

I also imported the the module using:

```
 Import-Module -Name <Path to the Invoke-MsBuild.psd1>
```

After importing it works,but when the current session is closed, the next time I try running this it again shows error. How can the module be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

From PowerShell 3.0 onwards, If you execute a cmdlet, PS is having the intelligence to do autoimport the module and this can be set using the automatic variable $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference to True, but There are some places where PS expects the module. I the module is in some custom path you have to explicitly import in every new session. Best place for custom module is Documents/WindowsPowerShell/Modules , if not existing , you can create this folder structure and place the module under module directory.

else you can have this `Import-Module` code in your profile script.

better have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Modules

regards,

kvprasoon

Comment: You have a valid point. My issue was solved by updating the powershell version to 5.0.